# Nothing happen when building boost with bjam

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, bjam

I tried to build boost 1.71.0 with minGW 6.3.0 (after a few searches I found [this tutorial](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Building%20Boost/)), apparently we can't directly build boost with mingw so I built bjam and then I ran the following command in the boost directory:

```
..\boost-jam-3.1.18\bin.ntx86\bjam.exe --prefix=[some-path]\boost32 toolset=gcc address-model=32 variant=debug,release link=static,shared threading=multi  install
```

And got the following output:

```
[path-to-boost]/tools/build/src/tools/types\adoc.jam:2: in load
rule Copyright unknown in module adoc.
[path-to-boost]\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
[path-to-boost]/tools/build/src/tools/types\register.jam:36: in load
[path-to-boost]\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
[path-to-boost]/tools/build/src/tools\stage.jam:18: in load
[path-to-boost]\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
[path-to-boost]/tools/build/src/tools\builtin.jam:27: in load
[path-to-boost]\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
[path-to-boost]/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:12: in load
[path-to-boost]\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
[path-to-boost]\tools\build\src\kernel\bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
[path-to-boost]\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

The problem is that it does not seems to have any error, but there is also nothing else (no folder created, no files, nothing). I tried to change a few things (run the 'install' command separately for example), but I always get this output and nothing more, so I wonder if I miss something, and what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is actually the error message. Apparently, there is something wrong with the comment style in adoc.jam. If you look at the file, you will see a ranged comment using the style

```
#|
Copyright...
|#
```

which is not recognized properly. Thus, line 2 contains an invalid statement.

If you add a `#` at the beginning of each comment line, bjam will process the file and you will see the next file containing the same error. I had to edit 7 files until I ran into a different type of error.

Comment: I succeed to build boost a few days ago without knowing what I did, but I accepted your answer so it can help others